# Finding the Rate of distance between hands of clock

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

First, I think I don't understand the problem which asks about the greatest rate of change in distance between the tips of the hands of clocks. Does it mean where the increasing of distance is the greatest in one minute? or what...?
I used the laws of cosine $x^2=10^2+7^2-20*7\cos(\theta)$ where $x$ is the distance between hands and $\theta$ is the angle between hands.

A clock has a minute hand of $10cm$ long and an hour hand of $7cm$ long.
The hands move at a constant rate (no jerking as in some clocks)

Problem : At what time is the distance between the tips of the hands changing at the greatest rate?

A. $12:00$

B. $12:05$

C. $12:10$

D. $12:15$

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the question. I used the Law of Cosine thinking that where the distance changes the best will be the answer. But it was not...

Comment: Do you know what $\theta$ would be at each of those times?

Comment: For A-> 0, B->(6*5)-(0.5*5)=30-2.5=27.5, C->(6*10)-(0.5*10)=60-5=55, D->(6*15)-(0.5*15)=90-7.5=82.5

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  It is a reference on formatting mathematical statements using MathJax.

Comment: I just found the answer by trying with hand or Trial and Error method suggested by Teg (-: but the site says I can't post the answer for my own question before 8 hours after asking since I'm a new user without 10 reputations... Anyway thanks so much for "jnh"for editing my problem and "Teg"for reminding me the useful and elementary step in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from $12:00$ to $12:01$, the change in distance $\delta x=3-\sqrt{149-140\cos 5.5}\approx-0.11$

from $12:05$ to $12:06$, $\delta x=\sqrt{149-140\cos27.5}-\sqrt{149-140\cos33}\approx-0.64$

from $12:10$ to $12:11$, $\delta x \approx -0.66$,

and from $12:15$ to $12:16$, $\delta x\approx -0.57$.

The change was largest at $12:10$ in $1$ minute among the given choices.

Thus, the answer for the time of greatest rate in distance is $(C)\,12:10$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\begin{array}{rcrcr}
\mbox{'hour hand'} & \to &
r_{\rm hh}\cos\pars{\omega_{\rm hh}t}\,\hat{x} & + & r_{\rm hh}\sin\pars{\omega_{\rm hh}t}\,\hat{y}
\\
\mbox{'minute hand'} & \to &
r_{\rm mh}\cos\pars{\omega_{\rm mh}t}\,\hat{x} & + & r_{\rm mh}\sin\pars{\omega_{\rm mh}t}\,\hat{y}
\end{array}\,,\quad
\left\vert%
\begin{array}{rcr}
r_{\rm hh} & \equiv & 7\ \mbox{cm.}
\\[2mm]
r_{\rm mh} & \equiv & 10\ \mbox{cm.}
\\[2mm]
\omega_{\rm hh} & \equiv & {2\pi \over 12\ \mbox{hours}}
\\[2mm]
\omega_{\rm mh} & \equiv & {2\pi \over 1\ \mbox{min.}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

> $$
> {\rm d}\pars{t} \equiv \sqrt{\bracks{%
> r_{\rm hh}\cos\pars{\omega_{\rm hh}t} - r_{\rm mh}\cos\pars{\omega_{\rm mh}t}}^{2}
> +
> \bracks{%
> r_{\rm hh}\sin\pars{\omega_{\rm hh}t} - r_{\rm mh}\sin\pars{\omega_{\rm mh}t}}^{2}}
> $$

With $\ds{{\rm D}\pars{t} \equiv {\dd\pars{t} \over r_{\rm mh}}}$
and $\ds{\mu \equiv {r_{\rm hh} \over r_{\rm mh}} < 1}$:
$$
{\rm D}^{2}\pars{t}
=1 + \mu^{2}  - 2\mu\cos\pars{\omega t}\,,\qquad
\omega \equiv \omega_{\rm mh} - \omega_{\rm hh}
$$

> \begin{align}
> 2{\rm D}\pars{t}\dot{\rm D}\pars{t}
> &=
> 2\mu\omega\sin\pars{\omega t}
> \\[1mm]
> 2\dot{\rm D}^{2}\pars{t} + 2{\rm D}\pars{t}\ddot{\rm D}\pars{t}
> &=
> 2\mu\omega^{2}\cos\pars{\omega t}
> \end{align}

The greatest rate occurs when $\ddot{{\rm D}}\pars{t} = 0$. Then,
$$
4\mu^{2}\omega^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\omega t}
=2{\rm D}^{2}\pars{t}\bracks{2\dot{\rm D}^{2}\pars{t}}
=2{\rm D}^{2}\pars{t}\bracks{2\mu\omega^{2}\cos\pars{\omega t}}
$$

> $$
> \mu\bracks{1 - \cos^{2}\pars{\omega t}}
> =\bracks{1 + \mu^{2} - 2\mu\cos\pars{\omega t}}\cos\pars{\omega t}
> =\pars{1 + \mu}^{2}\cos\pars{\omega t} -2\mu\cos^{2}\pars{\omega t}
> $$

$$
\mu\cos^{2}\pars{\omega t} - \pars{1 + \mu^{2}}\cos\pars{\omega t} + \mu = 0
\quad\imp\quad\cos\pars{\omega t} = \mu
$$

> $$
> \omega t_{n} = \arccos\pars{\mu} + 2n\pi\,,\qquad n\ \in\ {\mathbb Z} 
> $$
>   With these values of $t_{n}$ we'll have:
>   $$\left\lbrace%
> \begin{array}{rcl}
> {\rm D}_{n}\pars{t} & = & \root{1 - \mu^{2}}
> \\
> \dot{\rm D}_{n}\pars{t} & = & {\mu^{2} \over \root{1 - \mu^{2}}}\,\omega
> \end{array}\right.
> $$

Comment: !!Aww it's AWESOME!!

Comment: I'm sure this solution is much easier than it actually looks, isn't it? Especially if some of the variables were written in actual values...(ex. $w_{hh}, w_{mh}$ ) and if it was described with simpler expressions. (Wait,,I actually feel like there was a typo? $w_{mh}=\frac{2\pi}{1hr}=\frac{2\pi}{60min}$

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the net velocity vector will be larger when the hands' velocity vectors are perpendicular than when they are aligned, hence 12:15.